# Can I wire a water heater and tanning bed on the same 220V circuit?

Tags: electrical, water-heater

Can I wire a water heater and a tanning bed on the same 220V breaker. I live in Ohio.

Comment: How many amps is the breaker? How many amps is the heater? How many amps is the tanning bed? (And, as an aside, aren't you at all worried about melanoma?)

Answer (score 2):

[The 2014 NEC is adopted in Ohio](http://www.electricalcodecoalition.org/state-adoptions.aspx).

You need a dedicated circuit for these appliances:
Refrigerator, Freezer, Electric range, Microwave, Water heater, Washer, Dryer, Dishwasher/garbage disposal, Furnace, Heat pump, Air conditioner (central and window), Sump pump, Hot tub/Sauna/Jacuzzi

A furnace requires a dedicated circuit.[422.12]

Dwelling units require at least one receptacle outlet for the laundry area. [210-52(f)] Laundry receptacle outlets in dwelling units must be fed from a 20-ampere branch circuit. Receptacle outlets outside of the laundry area are not permitted on the laundry circuit. [210-11(c)(2)]

If an appliance is a chord and plug type and it exceeds 80% of the branch circuit rating then a dedicated outlet is required. If the appliance is fastened in place and is rated for more than 50% of the branch circuit then that circuit must be dedicated. [210-23(a)]

Here is a terrible reference, but:
http://electrical.about.com/od/appliances/qt/DedicatedCircuit.htm makes a good point, "A good rule of thumb is that if it has a motor, it needs its own circuit."

Comment: Do you have a code reference for all this? Many of those definitely do NOT *require* a dedicated circuit.

Comment: You're right, that IS a terrible reference. Sorry, I don't use about.com for my electrical advice and code requirements. I go to the source. .... And their rule of thumb about anything with a motor needing it's own circuit is rather absurd.

Answer (score 1):

**Even if you could it is not at all a good idea.** Bottom line is if the water heater is on a 30A circuit then you CANNOT do this unless the tanning bed draws approx. 6 amps or less, which is highly unlikely.

The max load on a 30A circuit is 30A, and the limitation is 125% of a continuous load (a storage water heater is to be considered a continuous load, so just under 24A for a 4500 watt unit) plus that of the non-continuous load.

> **210.19 Conductors — Minimum Ampacity and Size (A) Branch Circuits Not More Than 600 Volts. (1) General.**
>
> Branch-circuit conductors shall have an ampacity not less than the
>   maximum load to be served. Where a branch circuit supplies continuous
>   loads or any combination of continuous and noncontinuous loads, the
>   minimum branch-circuit conductor size, before the application of any
>   adjustment or correction factors, shall have an allowable ampacity not
>   less than the noncontinuous load plus 125 percent of the continuous
>   load.

Comment: Are all 220V circuits 30A? Are all water heaters?

One should never rely on "125%" margins, they are called "safety" margins for a reson.

Comment: @Sam, WHERE did I say all 240V circuits are 30A? Where did I say all water heaters? I said *"If it is a 30A circuit..."* .....And what is a ""safety margin"*??? I am not familiar with that term in the code book. Have you ever read NEC 210.19? ...... And why not rely on whatever the code book says? Are you implying that something that is code legal may for some reason not be safe?? That's a VERY bold assumption. .... And instead of just dropping a negative and your **opinion** show me where I am incorrect.

Comment: @Sam I think what Speedy means about 125% is, if you have a continuous load  (say 20A), it counts as 125% of that (25A) when tallying what is allowed on that circuit.  For instance the 125'd value of 25A, plus an intermittent load of 6A, would exceed 30A and would not be legal on a 30A circuit.   If you notice, water heater makers often game that rule by making them 23A.

Comment: @Sam, care to clarify?

Comment: @speedypetey  "unless the tanning bed draws approx. 6 amps or less" is incorrect because if the appliance (like a water heater) is fastened in place and is rated for more than 50% of the branch circuit then that circuit must be dedicated. A 24A water heater on 30A breaker is 80%. You would need a 50A breaker... larger wires... it's kind of a catch 22. By the time you satisfy all the rules, you end up having a dedicated circuit for a water heater.

Comment: @BenWelborn you're not using  210.24(A)(2) for this are you? If not tell me what code applies to what you are saying.

Comment: 210.23 (Permissable Loads) (A) Exception (2): Utilization Equipment Fastened in Place. The total rating of utilization equipment fastened in place, other than luminaires (lighting fixtures), shall not exceed 50 percent of the branch-circuit ampere rating where lighting units, cord-and-plug-connected utilization equipment not fastened in place, or both, are also supplied.

Comment: Yeah, that's for 15 & 20 amp circuits.

Comment: Actually, 210.23 Permissible Loads is comprehensive... indeed, it specifies 15 and 20 amps in a table, but 15 and 20 amps is not the only thing it is referring to. It reads, " In NO case shall the load exceed the branch-circuit ampere rating. An individual branch circuit shall be permitted to supply ANY load for which it is rated. Then (without respect to amperage) it says, "Exception (2): Utilization Equipment Fastened in Place...

Comment: @BenWelborn you can't twist the code to your liking, you have to take it as it is. Taking sections (or exceptions) out of context, is a good way to get things wrong.

Comment: No, 210.23(A) is 15 & 20 amp. 210.23(B) is 30 amp. 210.23(A) does not apply here.

Comment: Codes are written such that the sentence is the code, wherever it applies. Even the exceptions can be taken without context because logically, it stands alone. In other words, the total rating of utilization equipment fastened in place, other than luminaires (lighting fixtures), shall not exceed 50 percent of the branch-circuit ampere rating where lighting units, cord-and-plug-connected utilization equipment not fastened in place, or both, are also supplied. Period.

Comment: No Ben, you're wrong. You cannot simply apply a code to a section other than where it applies. I mean you can, but you are going above and beyond code if you do.

Comment: I have no idea if code allows this or if the product even exists but could you wire it up where the circuit runs through a 3 pole switch where only one outlet could receive power at a time?  Neither device seems like it should need 24/7 access to power but having to unplug/replug frequently may be worth installing the switch.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely.  I used an 8 ft. length of the appropriate wire, a receptacle that fit my tanning bed plug and wired straight into my hotwater heater. I put the receptacle in a utility box to make it safe and never had a problem. Everything was 220 volts.

Comment: How many amps/watts is your hot water heater, and how many amps/watts is your tanning bed?